# App crashes when I switch from a map activity to another activity, then back to the map activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a small app that receives your current GPS coordinates in latitude and longitude when a "Save Location" button is pressed.  Another activity is started where the map is shown and your current position is marked.  On this map activity, there is a button you can press to go to another activity (let's call this the memo activity), in which there is a button to bring you back to the map activity.  However, the app crashes upon pressing this button that brings you back to the map activity.

Here is the code for the main activity, map activity and the memo activity.

**Main Activity**

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button;
private TextView textView;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
private double longitude;
private double latitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}

public void saveAndGo(View view) {
    GPStracker g = new GPStracker(getApplicationContext());
    Location l = g.getLocation();
    if (l != null)
    {
        longitude =  l.getLongitude();
        latitude  =  l.getLatitude();
    }

    Intent go = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    go.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
    go.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
    startActivity(go);
    finish();
}
```

**Map Activity**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Double latitude;
private Double longitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        latitude = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("latitude");
        longitude = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("longitude");
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng pos = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title("Your Location"));
    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(16.0f);
    mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20.0f);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pos));
}

public void goMemos (View view) {
    Intent go = new Intent(this, MemoScreen.class);
    startActivity(go);
}
```

**Memo Activity**

```
public class MemoScreen extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.memoscreen);
    }

    public void goMap (View view){
        Intent go = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(go);
    }
}
```

I assume it's crashing because when I try to get data from the main activity when switching back to the map activity from the memo activity, the data is null.  The app runs just fine if I remove the getExtras() calls from the map activity.

How do I get around this?

Note: I would like to avoid using finish() in the memo activity since I plan to add more screens to this app, thus using that may end up in undesired behavior (i.e., returning back to the wrong activity).

Comment: share your crash log

Comment: The monitor states "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.os.BaseBundle.getDouble(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Apologies if this isn't what you were looking for

Comment: Your lat and long is null and can't be converted to double when navigating back from memo activity, either pass it to memo activity and when navigating back pass it as bundle or store it in variable in map activity and check for nulls

Comment: why you are creating a intent to create a new instance of map activity, simply just call onbackpress in goMap(). or otherwise if you want to create a new instance so when you are calling memo activity send latitude and longitude with it and deliver back to map activity from memo activity.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put simple condition that is

```
 if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){

    latitude = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("latitude");
    longitude = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("longitude");
 }
```

just use this in your mapsactivity
and not forgot to initialize the value of

```
private Double latitude=123.45;   
private Double longitude=123.45;
```